# TypeError: can't concat str to bytes. It does not look any byte object around. python3

Tags: python-3.x, string, byte

"TypeError: can't concat str to bytes" pops out at `read(1)` statement in following code.

```
def __init__(self, infile):
        self.infile = infile
        while self.infile.read(1) != 'T':
            pass
        else:
            .
```

infile is codecs.StreamReaderWriter object.

My system is Linux Debian, with python 3.11.4.

I am checking docs.python.org and other sites, but I have no idea where byte comes from.

I have changed infile to codecs.StreamReader object, but same error.

Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When parsing your data you're getting a StreamReaderWriter with binary data ([see docs here][1]) so either you'll want to convert your check string to bytes eg.

```
while self.infile.read(1) != b'T':
# do stuff
```

notice the "b" inserted before your string - otherwise decode your byte type data eg.

```
while self.infile.read(1).decode("utf-8") != 'T':
# do stuff
```

This is assuming the encoding of your data is utf-8 but you may need to verify that is an accurate assumption.
[1]: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.open

Comment: Thank you for your comment. apology for delayed response.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. apology for delayed response. However, problem persists. Error happens with "self.infile.read(1)", But one step ahead, error happens when coding of self.infile is unknown. Things go well when it is "utf-8". I assume that culprit is self,infile. I will update.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer, but one step ahead. I tried to extract the simplest sample.

Following code works

```
import codecs
fse = codecs.open("/path/to/text/file", "r", "utf_8")
fse.read(1)
```

While following code chokes, as the title reads

```
import codecs, io
codecinfo = codecs.lookup("utf_8")
fce = codecs.StreamReaderWriter(io.StringIO("bait"), codecinfo.streamreader, codecinfo.streamwriter)
fce.read(1)
```

Both of `fce` and `fse` are StreamReaderWriter object, one from file, the other from memory.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.